# can we apply two different regex to Extjs textfield which will show two separate error messages depending on regex?

Tags: extjs

Somewhat similar to like this -

```
{
  xtype     : 'textfield',
  name      : 'file_name',
  columnWidth : .60,
  maxLength   : 100,
  enforceMaxLength  : true,
  allowBlank  : false,
  regex     : /regx1/,
  regxText : "Error message1",
  regex : /regex2/,
  regexText : /Error message 2/
}
```

Comment: No, you can't. You would need to implement this as custom functionality.

Comment: You might want to look at this [link](http://devjs.eu/en/multiple-validation-multi-vtype-for-textfield-in-ext-js-4/).  I can't say I tried this particular thing, but I had used this site for another function I made and it worked perfectly.